# Customising the editor: (real) monospace font and dark theme (and more)

Tags: notebooks, customization, stylesheet, coding-style, editing

I don't know how to make the code editor in Mathematica present the code in a real 'monospace' font, with a dark, customisable theme (syntax highlighting and so on). This is something that keeps me away from working with Mathematica as my primary programming environment.

I mean, I like Mathematica, but I only use it like I used Derive in my old high school days: as a powerful tool for symbolic mathematics, plus some nice 2D and 3D graphics.

I'd like to use Mathematica as my main framework for scientific programming, ie:

- A customisable editor (in the terms I expressed at the beginning of this post).
- Separate code (files with functions and routines) from execution (console).
- A debugging environment.

Notebooks are fine, but can I have a classic programming environment?

Please help me with this basic question.

Answer (score 3):

you may want to check vscode + [lsp](https://github.com/kenkangxgwe/vscode-lsp-wl) or [lsp](https://github.com/WolframResearch/LSPServer)

[image]

- real 'monospace' font
- a dark, customisable theme
- (syntax highlighting and so on)
- A customisable editor (in the terms I expressed at the beginning of this post).
- Separate code (files with functions and routines) from execution (console).
- A debugging environment. (check [dap](https://github.com/kenkangxgwe/vscode-lsp-wl?tab=readme-ov-file#debug-adapter-features))